iOS Google AdMob: "Could not retrieve application configuration data" error with GADMobileAds initialization
I'm trying to initialize Google AdMob in my SwiftUI iOS app but getting this error:
Could not retrieve application configuration data with state = Not Ready
My setup:

Using latest Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK
Added test GADApplicationIdentifier in Info.plist
Added all required SKAdNetworkItems
Using SwiftUI with AppDelegate

My code:
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(
        application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil
    ) -> Bool {
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start { status in
            if let gadStatus = status.adapterStatusesByClassName["GADMobileAds"] {
                print(" SDK Status: gadStatus.state.rawValue)")
                print(" SDK Description: \(gadStatus.description)")
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}

Info.plist configuration:
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511</string>

I've tried: - Using test ID - Clean build folder - Removing derived data - Reinstalling pods But still getting the same error. What could be causing this issue?
What I tried:

First tried with CocoaPods implementation
Then tried with Swift Package Manager (SPM)
Removed Package.swift completely to avoid conflicts between CocoaPods and SPM
Cleaned the project and rebuilt after each change
Verified that GADApplicationIdentifier is correctly set in Info.plist
Made sure there are no duplicate framework references

What I expected:

GADMobileAds to initialize successfully with state = Ready (1)
No configuration data retrieval errors
Basic test banner ad to load using test ID

The error persists regardless of whether I use CocoaPods or SPM, and even after removing Package.swift completely.
